# Error seeding database in Rails error on attribute I'm not using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on the flight-booker project in The Odin Project.  I am trying to seed a database with 60 days worth of flights to and from 10 cities.  When I seed the database, I get this error:

> Created database 'flight_booker_development' Created database
> 'flight_booker_test'
> #Airport:0x00007f003f0c6f20 rails aborted! ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute
> `flight_id`
>
> ```
>       raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError, "can't write unknown attribute `#{name}`"
>       ^^^^^ /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
> ```
>
> /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:22:in `times' /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:22:in` block (3 levels)
> in ' /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:21:in `times' /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:21:in` block (2 levels)
> in ' /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:15:in `block in <main>' /home/stuart/repos/flight-booker/db/seeds.rb:14:in` '
> Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:setup => db:seed (See full trace by
> running task with --trace)

The problem seems to be that it is trying to write an attribute that I am not using.  Here is my seeds.rb file:

```rb
require "faker"

airports = %w[LAX DFW NYC DEN BOS MIA HOU PIT POR MIN]

airports.each { |city_code| Airport.create!(city_code: city_code) }

Airport.all.each do |departure|
  Airport.all.each do |arrival|
    next if departure == arrival
    puts departure
    duration = rand(100..300)
    flight_number = rand(1000..1999)
    frequency = rand(3..5)
    60.times do
      frequency.times do
        Flight.create!(
          origin_id: departure,
          destination_id: arrival,
          duration: duration,
          flight_number: flight_number,
          departure_time: Faker::Time.forward(days: 60, period: :all)
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I was trying to use flight_id to hold the flight number, but have changed that because I realized I had a flight_id column in my bookings table.  I am not doing anything with the bookings table at this time though.  I was getting this same error before and then I did a migration to remove flight_id and add_flight number to the flights table.  Here is the current schema.rb

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_12_09_210422) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "airports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "city_code"
  end

  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "flight_id", null: false
    t.index ["flight_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_flight_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "destination"
    t.string "origin"
    t.datetime "departure_time"
    t.integer "duration"
    t.bigint "destination_id", null: false
    t.bigint "origin_id", null: false
    t.integer "flight_number"
    t.index ["destination_id"], name: "index_flights_on_destination_id"
    t.index ["origin_id"], name: "index_flights_on_origin_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "bookings", "flights"
  add_foreign_key "bookings", "users"
  add_foreign_key "flights", "airports", column: "destination_id"
  add_foreign_key "flights", "airports", column: "origin_id"
end
```

Here the models/flight.rb file:

```rb
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking, foreign_key: "flight_id"
  has_one :origin_id, class_name: "Airport"
  has_one :destination_id, class_name: "Airport"
  validates :departure_time, presence: true
  validates :duration, presence: true
  validates :flight_number, presence: true
end
```

That is the only place that flight_id appears anywhere, but I still get the same error if I remove that line of code.
In the error it is referencing the seeds file line 23, which is the start of the Flight.create action.  It did previously try to create flight_id, but that has been changed to flight_number, and I have saved the file, and restarted the computer to be thorough.

Here is the flights_controller.rb file:

```rb
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_flight
  def index
    @flight = Flight.all
  end

  def new
    @flight = Flight.new
  end

  def create
    @flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
  end

  private

  def set_flight
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:id])
  end

  def flight_params
    params.require(:flight).permit(
      :airport,
      :flight_number,
      :origin,
      :origin_id,
      :destination_id,
      :destination,
      :duration,
      :departure_time,
      :arrival_time
    )
  end
end
```

I previously had flight_id as a permitted param, but that has been changed to flight_number.

So, I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to try next.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I would be happy to provide any additional information you might think is relevant.  Thank you.

Edit to add that I tried creating a table entry from the rails console and got the same error in irb.

> irb(main):001:0> Flight.create!(departure_time: "2022-12-25 11:11:11
> -0700", duration: 200, flight_number: 1599, origin_id: Airport.first, destination_id: Airport.last)   Airport Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
> "airports".* FROM "airports" ORDER BY "airports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
> [["LIMIT", 1]]   Airport Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "airports".* FROM
> "airports" ORDER BY "airports"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
> /home/stuart/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute.rb:211:in
> `with_value_from_database': can't write unknown attribute` flight_id`
> (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
>
> ```
>       raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError, "can't write unknown attribute `#{name}`"                                          
>
>       ^^^^^                                                                                                                                                                                               irb(main):002:0>
> ```

Comment: You still use flight_id in this line in your model: belongs_to :booking, foreign_key: "flight_id" I am not sure how to fix this, because this association feels totally wrong. A flight certainly dos not belongs to a booking, but a flight has many bookings and a booking belongs to a flight. I suggest reviewing all associations in the models and their required foreign keys in the database.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  I tried changing some things around, and I've reversed some of those associations and tried removing all foreign keys because at the moment I am only trying to seed the database with airports and flights.  I haven't done anything with booking at all.  Right now the word "flight_id" does not appear in my code anywhere, but I'm still getting that error.  I went into the postgres terminal to view the schema there and verified that flight_id is not part of the flights table.  I'm new and struggling to learn this.  I don't get why the error is persisting.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Please consider updating the code in your question when flight_id us not used in your flight .rb model anymore.

Comment: Thank you. I will do so in the morning. I really do appreciate you taking a look at this.  Most errors I can google and find the answer but this one is really eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined your assocation with `foreign_key: "flight_id"`

```ruby
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking, foreign_key: "flight_id"
end
```

This option is documented as:

> Specify the column used to store the associated object's type

Needless to say having a `flights.flight_id` column that references `bookings` is just wrong.

Lets scrub this broken attempt and try again. Stash you work in GIT and roll back and lets setup those models correctly.

To setup the assocation just between flights, airports and airlines you should use three tables and associate them like so:

```ruby
# rails g model airline name
class Airline < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :flights
end

# rails g model airport name iata_code
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :flights_as_origin,
    class_name: 'Flight',
    foreign_key: :origin_id
  has_many :flights_as_destination,
    class_name: 'Flight',
    foreign_key: :destination_id
end

# rails g model flight flight_number:string airline:references origin:references destination:references
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :airline
  # These should be belongs_to assocations
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Airport'
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Airport'
end
```

This is the data thats common to all passengers. You don't alter anything here when a passenger books a ticket. When creating the `flights` table you need to explicitly tell Rails that `destination_id` and `origin_id` should point to the `airports` table:

```ruby
class CreateFlights < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :flights do |t|
      # ...
      t.references :origin, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :airports }
      t.references :destination, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :airports }
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

To model the assocation between passengers, flights and bookings you actually want a many to many assocation with a join table:

```ruby
# rails g model ticket passenger_name:string flight:references seat:string
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :flight
end 

class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :flights, through: :tickets
end

class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :bookings, through: :tickets
end
```

Here you use the tickets table to store each item in an itenary so that you can actually model stuff like multi-leg trips and multiple passengers per booking.

Comment: I will take your advice and git stash this work and start fresh.  Your explanation makes sense.

Comment: It would probally make more sense to name the assocations in Airport `has_many :departures, class_name: 'Flight', foreign_key: :origin_id` and `has_many :arrivals, class_name: 'Flight', foreign_key: :destination_id` but I was trying to make it more obvious that you need a separate `has_many` assocation for each foreign key column on flights.